# Quasi-indefinite loop that I can't find the source of

Tags: c++

```
do {
   if (NewSBSize.X >= 0 && (unsigned)NewSBSize.X > text.size()) {
       int newpos = ((NewSBSize.X - text.size()) / 2); // Calculate the number of spaces to center the specific text.
       for (int i = 0; i = newpos;) std::cout << "ARES\nMENU\nSelect one of the following options by pressing one, two or three:\n1. Activate Virus\n2. Program Information\n3. Exit\n"; // Prints the spaces

       std::cin >> choice; 
       switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                Ares();
            break;
            case 2:
                ProgramInfo();
            break;
            case 3:
                menu();
            break;
            default:
                int newposa = ((NewSBSize.X - text.size()) / 2); // Calculate the number of spaces to center the specific text.
                for (int i = 0; i < newposa; i++) std::cout << "Invalid input! Press any key to continue . . .\n"; // Prints the spaces
                std::cin.ignore();
                system("CLS");
            }
        }
    } while (choice < 1 or choice > 3);
}
```

I can't find the source of the out of control loop. It stops, but after it has repeated numerous times. I have tried breakpoints and suggested fixes on the web but nothing has worked. The code runs and is error free, but the loop is quazi-indefinite. Any ideas which part of the code needs correcting?

Comment: If the first `if`'s condition is false then the `do/while` loop body won't do anything and it will keep repeating.

Comment: `i = newpos` in the `for` loops condition is probably meant to be `i == newpos` or something similar. Certainly not an assignment.

Comment: I'm struggling to find anything that is correct in this code :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is problem in the for loop:

```
        for (int i = 0; i = newpos;) std::cout << "ARES\nMENU\nSelect one of the following options by pressing one, two or three:\n1. Activate Virus\n2. Program Information\n3. Exit\n"; // Prints the spaces
```

There is no condition in the for-loop, so it does not know when it should stop.  Follow the for-loop syntax:

```
for ( init; condition; increment/decrement ) {
   statement(s);
}
```

Comment: That `for` loop doesn't seem to make sense even if fixed. Why print the instructions multiple times?

Comment: It's almost certainly supposed to be `for(int i=0; i< newpos; i++) std::cout << ' '; std::cout << "ARES\n....`